# JXtreeTable ignores getValueAt for tree-nodes

Tags: java, swing, swingx, treetable

I have a JXTreeTable, which has a tree of nodes (different datatypes) on the left side and a grid on the right side (as default).

Now I want that all displayed values (also the tree-captions) are taken from the getValueAt(row,column) method, but instead of the tree-nodes are rendered as by their toString() method

How can I force the JXTreeTable not to take the class-specific toString() and use the Value returned by getValueAt(...)?

thanks!

here is my model:

```
public class TreeTableGroupTreeTableModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel {

    private final static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "Tree",
            "Add/Edit", "Remove" };

    //Group-Hierarchy:
    private JXGroup groupRootObject;

    public TreeTableGroupTreeTableModel(JXGroup groupRoot) {

        this.groupRootObject = groupRoot;

    }

// Here is my structure:
//GROUP 1-1 ModuleAggregation 1-* Modules 1-1 JXGroupAccessMemberAggregation 1-* JXGroupAccessSimpleUserObjectLeaf

    /**
     * Returns the value for the node at columnIndex. The node must be managed
     * by this model. Unamanaged nodes should throw an IllegalArgumentException.
     * 
     * 
     * node - the node whose value is to be queried column - the column whose
     * value is to be queried
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(Object node, int column) {

        System.out.println(node.getClass());

        if (node instanceof JXGroup) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "this should render this string instead of the class tostring()";//((JXGroup) node);
            case 1:
            case 2:
                return "";
            }
        } else if (node instanceof JXGroupAccessModuleAggregation) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "Modules";
            case 1:
                return "ADD";
            case 2:
                return "REMOVE ALL";
            }
        } else if (node instanceof JXGroupAccessModule) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return ((JXGroupAccessModule) node).getModule();
            case 1:
                return "ADD";
            case 2:
                return "REMOVE";
            }
        } else if (node instanceof JXGroupAccessMemberAggregation) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "Members";
            case 1:
                return "ADD";
            case 2:
                return "REMOVE ALL";
            }
        } else if (node instanceof JXGroupAccessSimpleUserObjectLeaf) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                SimpleUserObject c = FunctionsUser.getUser(
                        metaDataPackage.getUsers(),
                        ((JXGroupAccessSimpleUserObjectLeaf) node).getUserId().getId());
                return c.getShowAs();
            case 1:
                return "";
            case 2:
                return "REMOVE";
            }
        } 

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value for the node at columnIndex to value. The node must be
     * managed by this model. Unamanaged nodes should throw an
     * IllegalArgumentException.
     * 
     * value - the new value node - the node whose value is to be changed column
     * - the column whose value is to be changed
     */
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, Object node, int column) {

        return; // changes are not allowed

    }

    @Override
    public Object getRoot() {
        return groupRootObject;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(Object node, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return node instanceof JXGroupAccessCategoryLeaf
                || node instanceof JXGroupAccessChapterLeaf
                || node instanceof JXGroupAccessEntryLeaf
                || node instanceof JXGroupAccessSimpleUserObjectLeaf;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object obj) {

        if (!(obj instanceof JXICountable)) {
            System.out.println("parsing error. should be JXCountable (but is "
                    + obj.getClass() + ")");
            return 0;
        }

        JXICountable obj2 = (JXICountable) obj;

        return obj2.getChildrenCount();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        if (parent instanceof JXITreeNodeAble) {
            return ((JXITreeNodeAble) parent).getChild(index);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "parent is not a member of JXITreeNodeAble");
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        if (parent instanceof JXITreeNodeAble) {
            return ((JXITreeNodeAble) parent).getIndexOfChild(child);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "parent is not a member of JXITreeNodeAble");
    }
}
```

Comment: This must be the swingx JXTreeTable (there is no JXTreeTable in standard swing), I added the swingx tag

Comment: Why don't you just use the `getValueAt(Object node, int column)`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all please note that tree table is one of the the most complex components because nodes have to keep a lot of data:

- Hierarchichal: given the parent-child relationship.
- User data: given the ability to keep and retrieve user-specific objects through `setUserObject(..)` and `getUserObject()` methods.
- Columns data: each node is responsible to retrieve the data associated to each column index in order to provide the ability to be represented in a tabular form.

In addition all nodes might keep different data objects, so the problem becomes even more complex.

### Update

Now that you have posted your code and the [source](http://javanbswing.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/swing-treetable-example-using.html) from where it is based, be aware that implementation is intended to have no root (the node you are having problems with) and works directly with domain objects to avoid deal with `TreeTableNodes`. There is a [subsequent post](http://javanbswing.blogspot.in/2013/09/swing-treetable-example-with-root-using.html) in which the author modifies it's tree table model implementation to include a root node. Having said this there are at least two things that you should modify:

1. Don't override `getRoot()` method and leave the implementation iherited from `AbstractTreeTableModel`.
2. Change your class constructor calling the appropriate `super` constructor.

In code:

```
public class TreeTableGroupTreeTableModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel {
    ...
//    private JXGroup groupRootObject; Not needed!
    ...
    public TreeTableGroupTreeTableModel(JXGroup groupRoot) {
        super(groupRoot);
    }
    ...    
//    @Override
//    public Object getRoot() {
//        return groupRootObject;
//    }
    ...
}
```

While this might work (I'm not able to test it without all your classes) I would like to emphasize one more time that this way to implement a tree table model doesn't feel right to me. I would not mess with tree table model at all in first place and use `DefaultTreeTableModel` instead. I would also implement a tree table node for each domain class that needs to be represented in the tree table. For example:

```
class JXGroupAccessModuleTreeTableNode extends AbstractMutableTreeTableNode {

    public JXGroupAccessModuleTreeTableNode(JXGroupAccessModule module) {
        super(module);
    }

    public JXGroupAccessModuleTreeTableNode(JXGroupAccessModule module, boolean allowsChildren) {
        super(module, allowsChildren);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int column) {
        JXGroupAccessModule module = (JXGroupAccessModule)getUserObject();
        switch (column) {
            case 0: return module.getModule();
            case 1: return "ADD";
            case 2: return "REMOVE";
                default: throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(column);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

To allow cells be editable you have to override both `setValueAt(Object value, int column)` and `isEditable(column)` methods as well: by default `AbstractMutableTreeTableNodes` are not editable.

Following this approach you'll get these benefits:

- There's no need mess with tree table model at all.
- If the tree structure needs to be changed you only have to re-order the nodes as needed. Once again there's no need to modify any model's code.
- The representation of each node is decoupled from the model so you can represent the same domain object in different ways just overriding a couple of methods in your tree table node (not model).

Comment: hi, I followed this example (which doens't use UserObject or AbstractMutableTreeTableNodes): http://javanbswing.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/swing-treetable-example-using.html. Is this the reason why it takes the value from the normal toStrign() of my e.g. Employee-class?

Comment: That's a total different way of use `JXTreeTable` because the author implements its own `TreeTableModel` to avoid working with `TreeTableNodes`. In this scenario I can't help you without seeing your code. Please consider edit your question including your tree table model. Interesting post BTW @Niko

Comment: Hi, I have added the model

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code. I was wondering for potential bottlenecks in implementing a `TreeTableModel` in that fashion. Now I have the answer: it's really difficult to debug/maintain. See tree tables are intended to work with `TreeTableNodes` and relies on those nodes to provide columns data through `getValueAt(int column)` method, as shown above. My best suggestions would be: 1) Discard the custom tree table model and use `DefaultTreeTableModel` which is designed to work with tree nodes. 2) Define many tree table nodes as you need in order to keep the grouping hierarchy. @Niko

Comment: so you say that just extending treetablenode will solve the problem? the thing is that I want to reuse these "JX-objects" for other treetables as well (with other values to return in getValueAt()). so I have to do the main rendering in the models' getValueAt() and not in every individual node-object...

Comment: or it is not designed to take the trees' value from the models' getValueAt? or is the problem that it has to be the object which is returned by getChild(index...) (which is e.g. a ModuleAggregation with all its children etc.) and I try to return a plain string?)

Comment: Please see my update. Hope it be more helpful this time. @Niko

Comment: Hi @kleopatra, sorry for bothering you. Could you please take a look to this case? Your feedback will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.